# L293D driver DC motors need help to start rotating

Tags: arduino-uno, motor

I set up this circuit which uses L293D motor driver IC to control two DC motors.

[image: LM298D motor driver]

+6V input is connected to unregulated power supply. It's current rating is 500 mA.

There is a connection between Arduino's ground line and power supplies ground line. There is a parallel 0.1 uF capacitor connected between motor terminal pins.

There is a wheel at the end of the motors but they don't have a gearbox. The wheels are suspended so that they can rotate freely.

The source code of the software is as follows.

```
#include <Arduino.h>

unsigned int firstMotorPositive = 8;
unsigned int firstMotorNegative = 7;
unsigned int enableFirstMotor = 9;
unsigned int secondMotorPositive = 5;
unsigned int secondMotorNegative = 4;
unsigned int enableSecondMotor = 3;

void setup()
{
    pinMode(firstMotorPositive, OUTPUT);
    /*  I've changed this part as shown by @timemage  */
    //pinMode(secondMotorPositive, OUTPUT); // <------
    pinMode(firstMotorNegative, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(enableFirstMotor, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(secondMotorPositive, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(secondMotorNegative, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(enableSecondMotor, OUTPUT);

    // All motors are off
    digitalWrite(firstMotorPositive, LOW);
    digitalWrite(firstMotorNegative, LOW);
    digitalWrite(secondMotorPositive, LOW);
    digitalWrite(secondMotorNegative, LOW);
}

void turnOnMotors()
{
    // Set motors to maximum speed
    // For PWM maximum possible values are 0 to 255
    analogWrite(enableFirstMotor, 255);
    analogWrite(enableSecondMotor, 255);


    // Turn on motor A & B
    digitalWrite(firstMotorPositive, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(firstMotorNegative, LOW);
    digitalWrite(secondMotorPositive, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(secondMotorNegative, LOW);
    delay(2000);

    // Turn off motors
    digitalWrite(firstMotorPositive, LOW);
    digitalWrite(firstMotorNegative, LOW);
    digitalWrite(secondMotorPositive, LOW);
    digitalWrite(secondMotorNegative, LOW);

    analogWrite(enableFirstMotor, 0);
    analogWrite(enableSecondMotor, 0);

}

void speedControl()
{
    digitalWrite(firstMotorPositive, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(firstMotorNegative, LOW);
    digitalWrite(secondMotorPositive, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(secondMotorNegative, LOW);


    analogWrite(enableFirstMotor, 63);
    analogWrite(enableSecondMotor, 63);

    delay(3000);

    analogWrite(enableFirstMotor, 127);
    analogWrite(enableSecondMotor, 127);
    delay(3000);

    analogWrite(enableFirstMotor, 191);
    analogWrite(enableSecondMotor, 191);
    delay(3000);
/*
    analogWrite(enableFirstMotor, 255);
    analogWrite(enableSecondMotor, 255);
    delay(3000);
*/


    // All motors are off
    digitalWrite(firstMotorPositive, LOW);
    digitalWrite(firstMotorNegative, LOW);
    digitalWrite(secondMotorPositive, LOW);
    digitalWrite(secondMotorNegative, LOW);
    analogWrite(enableFirstMotor, 0);
    analogWrite(enableSecondMotor, 0);
}

void loop()
{

    /*
      turnOnMotors();
      delay(1000);
    */

    speedControl();
    delay(1000);
}
```

The problem is they need help to start rotating. They will only start rotating if I physically twist the shaft with my fingers first.

As far as I know the motors used in this circuit are two 6 volt DC motors.

When I measure the maximum voltage between motor terminals I read about 0.5 volts. If I twist the shaft I read about 4.5 volts.

Comment: does the motor spin when connected directly to the power supply?

Comment: Yes. If I connect motors to simple 1.5 volts battery it spins.

Comment: I've already tried that but it doesn't help either.

Comment: It is also possible that there are physical problems in the wiring.  A clear picture of your actual wiring end to end may help someone spot something.

Answer (score 1):

The L2978D is a terrible motor driver (I really wish people wouldn't use it!). It is "bipolar" which means that both the high and low side switches of the H-bridge are Bipolar Junction Transistors. This means that you get about 1.4V voltage drop in total between the inputs and outputs.

To counter that you must provide at least 1.4V more than your motors need for them to operate properly.

Comment: I switched to unregulated power supply to 7.5 volts. I measured unregulated voltage with a DIMM. It was about 12.8 volts. Still, motors don't start. I've also tried with 9 volts. They don't also start with 9 volts.

Answer (score 0):

### no pinMode(firstMotorNegative, OUTPUT)

Well, here's a start at least:

```
pinMode(firstMotorPositive, OUTPUT);
pinMode(secondMotorPositive, OUTPUT); // <------
pinMode(enableFirstMotor, OUTPUT);
pinMode(secondMotorPositive, OUTPUT);
pinMode(secondMotorNegative, OUTPUT);
pinMode(enableSecondMotor, OUTPUT);
```

You are never setting `firstMotorNegative` to `OUTPUT` and probably intended to on the second line of this excerpt.

### firstMotorNegative floating or pulled high

The AVR GPIO pins are `INPUT` on power-up.  Writing to the PORT register, which is what `digitalWrite` does, takes on a different meaning when the pin's mode is `INPUT`.  That is, it enables or disables the pull-up internal resistors.  In other words, your     `digitalWrite(firstMotorNegative, HIGH);` and `digitalWrite(firstMotorNegative, LOW);` are effectively toggling between `pinMode(firstMotorNegative, INPUT_PULLUP)` and  `pinMode(firstMotorNegative, INPUT)` respectively.

So your L293D is seeing either this signal being weakly pulled up or floating.  During the floating condition in particular maybe a problem when you're doing:

```
// Turn on motor A & B
digitalWrite(firstMotorPositive, HIGH);
digitalWrite(firstMotorNegative, LOW);
```

... because you're disabling the pull-up here, the "negative" pin is `INPUT`/floating rather than reliably `LOW`.  So, it may be being intermittently interpreted as `HIGH` at the L293D, in which case there is no movement while that's happening.

Comment: Thanks I've edited the code as you suggested. But practically there is no difference.

Comment: @Erdem I will look for more problems again later and update this if I find anything I'm reasonably certain is a problem.

Answer (score 0):

That is operating as expected. Take a look at the data sheet. You can lose 1.8 volt on each output pin. Since you are in bridge configuration you now lose 3.6 Volts.  Now assume your power is 6VDC with 1 volt ripple. That adds to the voltage drop through the driver so rounding it out you lose 4 volts from your supply (not counting wiring loses) before you start, that is assuming the voltage does not droop. Two simple solutions, use a power supply with more voltage or go to a MOSFET bridge device.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I have an adjustable DC adapter which provides unregulated 1.5 V, 3 V, 4,5 V, 6 V, 7.5 V, 9 V and 12 V with up to 500 mA of current. I graudually switched from 6 volts to 12 volts. But motors don't spin. This confuses me since one of the motor with a small wheel attached starts spinning with only 1.5 volts battery but doesn't spins with an external DC adapter. I switched DC adapter to 6 V and measured unregulated voltage with a DIMM. It was about 17 volts. Isn't it a huge voltage for for such a small toy DC motor?

Comment: Your best bet is to use a regulated power supply with enough power to drive your load with some spair. An unregulated power supply has ripple, the amount depending on the design and components chosen. Not knowing your DMM and your adapter I can only guess but try measuring the output voltage in the AC range, it should be almost nothing. If you get a value it is a rough approximation of your AC content.

Comment: I use pen type [Mastech MS8211D](http://www.mastech-group.com/products.php?cate=120&PNo=245)  multimeter. I switched unregulated DC adapter to 6 volts setting. I selected AC and used max function to measure maximum voltage. This is quite interesting because it reads maximum voltage as 5.1 volts AC. Also DC voltage was about 10.5 volts.

Comment: I think we need to go back to the beginning and have you go to this link https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/ It is teaches the basics of electronics. While you are studying that get a regulated 10 or 12 volt power source rated at 2 amps or more. If you are in this for the long hall get a Lab Power supply, that runs about $60 on ebay, possibly a Christmas present. The only common thread is the power supply you are using. Also get an Arduino motor shield with FET outputs. This should get rid of the unknowns and get you started.